# iOS 7 AutoLayout sticky button to bottom screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, constraints, autolayout

I have read lot of documents and tutorials about autolayout and constraints but I don't know what I'm doing wrong but in my case the examples doesn't work...I know that this is a repeated question but I don't know what I can do...

I'm trying to fix a button to my bottom screen. Bottom with 0 distance. In 4 hinches screen all is ok but when I'm changig to 3,5" the button dissapear. This is what I'm doing:

[image: Selecting button]
[image]
[image]
[image]

1. Normal button
2. Select button and add the bottom space constraint
3. Button look likes fine
4. When screen size changes, the button dissapears

Thanks a lot!

Comment: disable auto-layout and continue... there will be no such issues... if you know auto-kayout very well, then only use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can complete the following steps to achieve that:

1. Add bottom constraint, width and height:
   [image]
2. Add horizontal centre constraint:
   [image]
3. Now you can test on your storyboard by clicking the Apply from factor button: [image: form factor button]
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the button, and select "Update Frames"

[image]

---

**Suggestion**: you should add constraints to the button for **left**, **right** and **height**.

Comment: Update Frames had no effect, BUT your suggestion was good, the problem was that I had no defined height....thanks!

Comment: @pekpon, hah, enjoy your iOS life